# Why would you create a variable with value this

Tags: javascript, this

I've seen this done alot in JavaScript and I do remember finding out why but I can't remember the answer.

I'm guessing it's something to do with scope and a function being called outside the "class" but why would one do this (preferably outlining an example):

```
function myClass ()
{
    var self = this;

    //...

    this.myArray = [];

    this.myFunc = function () { alert(self.myArray.length); };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to latch onto the variable as part of a [*closure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).

For example:

```
MyClass.prototype.doStuff = function(){
  this.foundItems = [];
  var self = this;
  this.myString.replace(/.../,function(){
    // `this` is actually the `window` inside this callback
    // so we need to use `self` to invoke another method on our instance object
    self.foundItems.push( self.doOtherStuff() );
  });
};
```

The specific example you wrote does not need a closure if you invoke the method in the expected way:

```
function Foo(){
  this.array = [];
  this.myFunc = function(){
    return this.array;
  }
}
var foo = new Foo;
foo.myFunc(); // []
```

However, it's possible to 'break' it like so:

```
var f2 = foo.myFunc;
f2(); // undefined, since `this` was the window
```

Your code using the closure, on the other hand, is safe against this sort of tomfoolery.

Comment: So in my example (now updated), would I still need the `self` before accessing `myArray` in function `myFunc`?

Comment: This specific example is not very good, `forEach` takes a second argument which will be bound to `this` inside the callback, which should be preferred over creating the "hacky" `self` variable.

Comment: @Ben It depends on how the method is invoked. For example: `var o = { f:function(){ return this } }; o.f()==o; /*true*/ var f2=o.f; f2()==window; /*true*/`

Comment: @Esailija Yes, `forEach` (and some other modern ones, like `map`) have a workaround for this problem. I'll switch the demo back to the less-common `replace`-with-callback.

Comment: @Phrogz You might probably be interested to know that there is a generic workaround for any function with `Function.prototype.bind` or `jQuery.proxy`

Answer (score 2):

"this" refers to the current "object". 
The power resides, when talking about javascript, into the fact that the "this" expression is evaluated context-wise, so for example if a method is executed in another object context, the "this" value will change respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a function within another function, `this` for the inner function gets set to the global window object. If you create a variable saving the value of `this`, like

```
var that = this;
```

then you can use `that` to reference the outer function within the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to some of the answers posted by other users, creating variable set to this allow you to reuse variables without accessing objects.

Similar to doing something like:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('someElement');
```

And then accessing myElement if you need to rather than document.getElementById multiple times.

Setting that = this or self = this gives you access everywhere to "that" or "self" and prevents from re-loading some object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one really wants to do that:

- Any time an instance is created, you also create a "copy" of the function. So 5 instances, will create 5 "copies" of the function.
- That "copy" of a function is bound to an environment that is only relevant to that specific instance, so it cannot be used generically. That means an extending class will get a method that is only relevant for some instance of the parent class that is probably not even used.
- Your indentation will get out of hand especially if you start nesting those inline functions
- You'll have to hunt for functions inside other functions instead of just looking it up in the prototype definition

An alternative:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myArray = [];
    this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this); //The "blueprint" in the prototype is not affected, the instance gets its own bound version.
                                           //This means the one in prototype can be inherited or used generically anywhere else as well
}

MyClass.prototype = {

    myFunc: function() { //My func is neatly listed in the prototype and can use `this` normally
        alert(this.myArray.length);
    },

    constructor: MyClass
};


var myObj = new MyClass();

document.addEventListener( "click", myObj.myFunc ); //Will now work as you "expect" it to work
```

A few drawbacks:

- Each bound function is a new function so per instance, 1 new function is still created every time.
- Boilerplate in writing out all the `.bind` calls in the constructor, though can be mitigated with a helper like `_.bindAll`